# Fitting an a div with 2 divs with HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following code for a basic layout(I'm a beginner btw) of a website:

http://jsfiddle.net/gvyL2ohc/

```
#Content {

    background-color:black;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 
}
```

I can't figure out how to make the black part of the "Content" fit that empty area between header,footer and navigation. It should just fill that area and work on all browsers. How can I do that using only HTML and CSS?

Comment: Why you don't give fixed width and height to the #content?

Comment: check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/gvyL2ohc/1/)

Comment: Where does the image take place in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/gvyL2ohc/2/

Just add this to your css

```
#Content {
  background-color: black;
  height: 620px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! How did you think of it? I mean was it trial and error or something else?

Comment: I kinda just checked your code and figured out that this would be best solution :)

Comment: But how did you figure out the exact number? Also,how how did you know this would work on every browser :s? Sorry for the noobish questions :s

Comment: I figured exact numbers by looking at your `#Left_Nav` element css properties and why wouldn't it work on every browser, this is basic css.

Comment: Whoops! Didn't realise the left left nav thing xD. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I am glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your jsfiddle link and found that you need to add **width:200px** or more in **#Content div**

Comment: Thanks ,I added the height and padding :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using fixed layout and not responsive or fluid below code should work for you.
few changes i have made in your markup

1. I have added a div mainWrapper which will wrap your all containers (header , footer , ContentWrapper) .this mainWrapper is given fixed width of 726px this same width will be taken by all is child containers (header , footer , ContentWrapper).
2. I have wrapped your left navigation and content div both in one wrapper ContentWrapper which is having fixed height of 600px and then with jquery i have set the same height to both left navigation and content .
3. In ContentWrapper you have two boxes #Left_Nav and #Content i have divided the total width of ContentWrapper (726px ref point no.1) in between them

   ## left_nav (200px) + #Content (526px) =  ContentWrapper(726px).

Note: If your layout is not fixed this will not work and we have to use some different ways to get it done.

```js
var height = $('#ContentWrapper').outerHeight();
$('#Left_Nav , #Content').height(height)
```

```css
.mainWrapper {
  width: 726px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#Header {
  background-color: #85D6FF;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
#Left_Nav {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #FFD9D9;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#Content {
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 526px;
}
#Footer {
  background-color: #C8C8C8;
  color: black;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
.hor {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.list_vertical {
  padding: 0px 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.list_horizontal {
  list-style: none;
}
h3 {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#ContentWrapper {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body bgcolor="#646464">
  <div class="mainWrapper">
    <div id="Header">Header</div>
    <div id="ContentWrapper">
      <div id="Left_Nav">
        <h3>Navigation</h3>

        <ul class="list_vertical">
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Link 0</li>
          <li>Link 1</li>
          <li>Link 2</li>
          <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="Content">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer">
      <div class="table">Footer
        <ul class="list_horizontal">
          <li class="hor">Link 0</li>
          <li class="hor">Link 1</li>
          <li class="hor">Link 2</li>
          <li class="hor">Link 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer,although it is a bit complicated for me :s. I will go through it though :)